# Auto answer prompts of jar file from shell

Tags: java, shell

I have a jar file that I invoke by shell

```
/usr/bin/java -jar app.jar
```

When started it prompts for 3 different questions

How can I pass the answers directly from shell?

I tried with echo or printf but it doesn't work...
I get

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
```

Comment: Need to look at relevant code

Comment: A possible solution is using [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)

Comment: @DarshanLila...no access to the code :(

Comment: @EugeniuRosca ...expect is not present on the server and no rights to install

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a temporary file to store the results before running the jar, and give the jar as the input using `<`.

Example (In my windows ) -

```
echo "Hello" > temp.out & echo "Bye" >> temp.out & java a < temp.out
```

Output -

```
Enter one line:
You entered - "Hello"
Enter second line:
You entered - "Bye"
```

For linux/shell, you can maybe use -

```
echo "First prompt" > temp.out && echo "Second prompt" >> temp.out && .... && /usr/bin/java -jar app.jar < temp.out
```