# how to pass parameters to an external program in bash

Tags: bash, arguments

I am trying to automate an external program that asks two inputs from user. I have the values in variables, but I m not able pass them to the program. What I do currently is to show the parameters on the screen, and ask users to copy/paste them. Then the external program runs fine.

**My current solution:**

```
printf "param-1: \"%s\"\n" "$param1"
printf "param-2: \"%s\"\n" "$param2"
printf "please copy and paste the values when they are asked"

result=$(java -jar external-app.jar decrypt -keyFormat b64)

printf "result: \"%s\"\n"
```

**I tried the followings but non of them worked:**

```
( echo "$param1"; echo "$param2" ) | java -jar external-app.jar decrypt
( echo "$param1"; echo "$param2" ) java -jar external-app.jar decrypt
java -jar external-app.jar decrypt < echo "$param1"
java -jar external-app.jar decrypt < "$param1"
```

**UPDATE**

**This is how a normal run looks like:**

```
$  java -jar external-app.jar decrypt 
encryptionKey: xxx
value: yyy
```

Try 1:

```
( echo "aaaa"; echo "bbbb" ) | java -jar  external-app.jar decrypt 
encryptionKey: value: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Try 2:

```
$ java -jar external-app.jar decrypt < echo "aaa"
bash: echo: No such file or directory
```

Try 3:

```
$ echo "aaa" > temp.out & echo "bbb" >> temp.out & java -jar external-app.jar decrypt < temp.out
[1] 13350
[2] 13351
encryptionKey: value: Exception in thread "main" 
Failed to obtain encryption key from the passed input
Caused by: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters.
```

Comment: have your tried : java -jar myjar.jar 'first argument' 'second argument'

Comment: Your first attempted solution should work if your program is reading from stdin. For example: `( echo foo ; echo bar ) | bash -c 'read -r value1 ; read -r value2 ; declare -p value1 value2'` prints both values as expected. Do you know for sure `external-app.jar` is reading from stdin, or could it be reading directly from the terminal? Many programs that read sensitive data (which `decrypt` makes me believe could be at play) choose not to read stdin to help protect that data.

Comment: Only nitpick on the first solution is you could make it a little more efficient by removing the subshell and replacing it with a command group, such as `{ echo foo ; echo bar ; } | cmd_that_reads_stdin`.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204629/auto-answer-prompts-of-jar-file-from-shell

Comment: Also a final comment, clarification on `I tried the followings but non of them worked` would go a long way toward helping. What does it mean for them to not work? Wrong output? Error messages? Did you have to manually answer the prompts?

Comment: I updated the post, could you please check it?

Comment: `NullPointerException` seems like something worth investigating. Does the stack trace point at one of the values you're supposed to be supplying?

Comment: Yes, I can investigate the java source code and fix it, but my objective is not this. We have an existing JAR that asks user to input two values and I would like to use it from bash in an automated way. Unfortunately I have no time to rewrite the Java code now

Comment: I'm not necessarily suggesting you rewrite the java code, but investigating the exception may explain why the program works when you manually answer the prompts but not when you pass data on stdin. You correctly passed your data to stdin, so the most likely problems are either the program doesn't correctly read stdin or else it doesn't read stdin at all. We don't have a copy of your java code so we can't tell you what the problem is, we can only speculate.

Comment: Remove the `&`s in *try 3*